# How to remove dependency from libraryDependencies that was added by plugin?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

I have a very classic `build.sbt` for Play 2.3 Scala project with the following `libraryDependencies` setting:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatestplus" % "play_2.10" % "1.1.0" % "test"
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.9.5" % "test"
)

lazy val portal = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

The `PlayScala` plugin adds `specs2` dependency that "pollutes" classpath and makes good import harder in IDE.

How can I remove a dependency from `libraryDependencies`?

Comment: See [playframework / framework / project / Dependencies.scala ](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/17d037e06ebf135b06c5309e674a21b59781f140/framework/project/Dependencies.scala). Playframework is very tightly coupled with specs2.

Comment: Yes. But for test only. Each use in dependency is mapping it in the test scope. So If I don't use Specs2 nor play-specs2 integration but only scalatest with play-scalatest integration, I believe it should work. I think that Specs2 dependency are still there because scalatest integration is quite recent (since 2.2.x) but it provide all what is needed.

Comment: See Exclude Transitive Dependencies topic at: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved a similar problem by adding the following to my `Build.scala`:

```
def excludeSpecs2(module: ModuleID): ModuleID =
  module.excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "org.specs2"))

val main = Project(appName, file("."))
  .enablePlugins(play.PlayScala)
  .settings(libraryDependencies ~= (_.map(excludeSpecs2)))
```

Answer (score 7):

I succeeded. Thanks Venkat, I knew the exclude, but as I did not declare the dependency myself, I didn't know where to use it.

It was very simple: redeclare by myself the dependency added by the plugin :

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatestplus" % "play_2.10" % "1.1.0" % "test",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.9.5" % "test",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-test" % play.core.PlayVersion.current % "test" exclude("org.specs2", "specs2-core_2.10") exclude("org.specs2", "specs2-junit_2.10") exclude("org.specs2", "specs2-mock_2.10") exclude("org.specs2", "specs2-matcher-extra_2.10") exclude("org.specs2", "") exclude("com.novocode", "junit-interface") exclude("com.google.guava", "guava") exclude("com.google.code.findbugs", "jsr305")
)
```

Maybe not very elegant, but it works.